# Getting Error in Json Conversion in Android SDK 28

Tags: java, android, xml

I have getting this error of fetching data and store in json format. So please help me

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
linkinStream = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: Hi. Where is the error?

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Please provide us information with error message. Otherwise its hard to help you.

Comment: at com.wingcompiler.utils.JsonUtils.getJSONString(JsonUtils.java:73)
        at com.wingcompiler.AsyncTask.LoadAbout.doInBackground(LoadAbout.java:30)
        at com.wingcompiler.AsyncTask.LoadAbout.doInBackground(LoadAbout.java:13)

Comment: Here is my jsonUtils File Link-https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bh2RSehGaqz6M0jiv-HhV5PxG9Q3SXb1

Comment: Here is my LoadAbout File Link please help me guys - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lgSKkTSX81GsDJOB214xvy6XOPP_pyAN